# Rust: How to solve "one type is more general than the other" error when using thread local OnceCell?

Tags: rust, global-variables, thread-local-storage

I'm on 1.70 version of rust playing with recently added `OnceCell` in std.

I'm trying to create global configuration object in `thread local` storage wrapped in `OnceCell`.
I do that purposefully to avoid unnecessary synchronization overhead of `std::sync::OnceLock` since my application will be single threaded.

Here's some sample code:

```rust
thread_local! {
    static CONFIGURATION: OnceCell<Configuration> = OnceCell::new();
}

pub fn init() -> Result<(), ConfigurationLoadingError> {
    let configuration = Configuration::try_from_file()?;
    CONFIGURATION.with(|cell| {
        cell.get_or_init(|| configuration);
    });
    Ok(())
}

pub struct Configuration {
    source_file: PathBuf,
    // ...
}

pub struct ConfigurationLoadingError;
```

The issue appears when I try to access `CONFIGURATION` in main:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), ConfigurationLoadingError> {
    init()?;
    let default_config = CONFIGURATION.with(|cell| cell.get()).unwrap();
    let _reader = BufReader::new(
        File::create(&default_config.source_file)?);
    Ok(())
}
```

On compilation compiler reports the following:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:70:52
   |
70 |     let default_config = CONFIGURATION.with(|cell| cell.get()).unwrap();
   |                                              ----- ^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                                              |   |
   |                                              |   return type of closure is Option<&'2 Configuration>
   |                                              has type `&'1 OnceCell<Configuration>`                        ^
```

I'm guessing that compiler has no way of knowing that contents of `OnceCell` will never change, which alongside `CONFIGURATION` being global means that references to `CONFIGURATION` are effectively `'static`.

So, my question is: Is there any non-unsafe way for me to informing the compiler that reference to `CONFIGURATION` contents will indeed live long enough? Perhaps I'm terribly misusing the `OnceCell` api? From examples that I've seen this seems like a main use-case for this type and as such I would expect that using it would be unsafe free (and little less verbose).

Here's [minimal working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec02b8e9030ec345d6468f4ee9ea87d8) on playground.

I know that there are many crates that supply functionality I'm trying to implement -- This project is only for educational purposes only.

### Offtop

Btw I've tried initializing `CONFIGURATION` using `OnceCell::from` directly without using `new` and `get_or_init` but then I cannot bubble up loading errors to `main` and exit with an error. These kinds or errors are expected outcome of the program so `panic` does not fit here. I considered `std::process::exit` but I'm not too sure about the destructor situation described in docs:

> If a clean shutdown is needed it is recommended to only call this function at a known point where there are no more destructors left to run; or, preferably, simply return a type implementing Termination (such as ExitCode or Result) from the main function and avoid this function altogether

So I followed the advice to simply return errors from `main`. Is there any reason why to worry about calling `exit` here? It there a better way of doing it altogether without any external crates?

I've tried searching on SO and other forums but with this feature being so new there was nothing to be found.

Comment: Seems like something is broken. Anyway, here's a muuuch shorter version https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37a277c32fe6b0959bae8383b8076ffe

Comment: Note that if your application is single-threaded, then `OnceLock` will probably be faster than thread-local `OnceCell` (although of course measure yourself), since on `OnceLock` there will be non-contended cold initialization then a very cheap (atomic) check every access, but a thread-local `OnceCell` will involve accessing the TLS on every access.

Comment: Nitpick: you can replace your `get_or_init()` with `set()`. But it is better to just use `get_or_try_init()` and load the config inside the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just as with any other thread-local: the compiler cannot prove you won't move the reference to your data to another thread and use it after the original thread was destroyed, i.e. a use-after-free.

My advice: just use `OnceLock` in a normal `static`. As I wrote in a comment, it'll probably be even faster.

But if you really want, you can wrap your data in `Rc` and clone it:

```rust
thread_local! {
    static CONFIGURATION: OnceCell<Rc<Configuration>> = OnceCell::new();
}

pub fn init() -> Result<(), ConfigurationLoadingError> {
    let configuration = Configuration::try_from_file()?;
    CONFIGURATION.with(|cell| {
        cell.get_or_init(|| Rc::new(configuration));
    });
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ConfigurationLoadingError> {
    init()?;
    let default_config = CONFIGURATION.with(|cell| Rc::clone(cell.get().unwrap()));
    let _reader = BufReader::new(
        File::create(&default_config.source_file)?);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd38c3f3581e91741c3a49a5ad61c25c).

Comment: ohh right I see. Thanks for pointing out the performance characteristics of both approaches in your comment. I'll make sure to benchmark both of them. As an afterthought I seems clear to me that I was expecting a bit too much from a simple struct like `OnceCell` which is just a thing to guarantee single initialization (and **only** that) not some profound language concept. Thanks again.

Comment: @dynamically_dispatched42 This is not related to `OnceCell`, the compiler is right: if your application wasn't single-threaded (which it cannot know), this was unsound.